# How to decrement one field and increment another field atomically in java using concurrency classes

Tags: java, concurrency, atomic

I have a state machine - pending and completed - AtomicLong (threaded). I need to decrement pending and increment completed in an atomic fashion

```
private final AtomicLong pending = new AtomicLong();
private final AtomicLong completed = new AtomicLong();

void markComplete() {
  this.pending.decrementAndGet();
  this.completed.incrementAndGet();
}
```

I can make this atomic by synchronising using a block. But that seems to defeat the use of using concurrent objects.

```
synchronized void markComplete() {
  this.pending.decrementAndGet();
  this.completed.incrementAndGet();
}
```

I wish to know if there is a niftier way of doing this?

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: A synchronized block with just two atomic statements in it does not strike me as a big performance problem.  What issue do you have with it?

Comment: Do these values have to be `long`? If two `int` values would suffice you could pack these into a `long` by doing `((long) completed) << 32 + pending`. Incrementing completed would mean adding 1L<<32, decrementing pending would mean adding -1

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks. Question was not in performance, it was to understand if there is a concurrent api way of achieving this because if I need to synchronise at a method level, then might as well use normal `long` as field type.

Comment: The question is on atomic operations. @ThomasKläger I am assume that bit wise operations may be atomic depending on the run time - architecture. But safe to assume that in general they are not atomic. Thanks for your comment though.

Comment: There is no need to do bitwise operations to update the state: `long current = this.pending.addAndGet(1L<<32-1); long currentCompleted = current >> 32; long currentPending = current & 0xffffffff;`. The bitwise operations occur after changing the shared state

Comment: @ThomasKläger, I have revised the code snippet, the state in pending and completed is whats important. Can you pls advice?

Comment: simply put - you can't. you need `synchronized` (or some other type of lock) or make them part of a `AtomicReference<Holder>` where `Holder` encapsulates both values

Comment: but the question still stands - can you use `int` instead? you might get away with a dirty hack of using `LongAdder` in the sense that the first 32 bits would represent the increment and last 32 decrement

Comment: Thanks @Eugene I got a couple of leads `AtomicReference` and `LongAdder` to look into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `pending` and `complete` fit into the `int` range (and as long as pending is greater than zero when you call `markComplete()`) you could do something along these lines:

```
private final AtomicLong pendingAndComplete = new AtomicLong();

void markComplete() {
  this.pendingAndComplete.addAndGet(1L<<32-1); // this is atomic
}
void markPending() {
  this.pendingAndComplete.incrementAndGet(); // this is atomic
}

void doSomething() {
  long current = this.pendingAndComplete.get(); // this fetches the current state atomically

  int currentCompleted = (int)(current >> 32);
  int currentPending = (int) current;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't update `currentPending`, since it's derivable. Leave it fixed and use this:

```
public long getCurrentPending() {
    return currentPending.get() - completed.get();
}
```

you can always increase `currentPending` when you add items without breaking anything.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But the object is a state machine. Fields `pending` and `completed` are both AtomicLong types. The state of these fields is important to the state machine. I will revise the post for clarity.

Comment: @SudhirR I don't think you are understanding me: you can use this method instead of accessing the field directly (and instead of updating `currentPending`).

Answer (score 0):

Concurrent objects are usefull only for making one value thread safe. If you want to have concurency over multiple values you will have to use locking (as in synchronized)